# Writing the Lagrangian and the dual of this primal problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

We have the following primal problem

$$\min_{ \mathbb W_{i,j} \in \mathbb R, \, \xi_{i,j} \in \mathbb R,  \, b \in \mathbb R^m} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} \xi_{i,j} + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} \mathbb W_{i}^2$$

such that

$$\mathbb W_i x_i + b_{y_i} - \mathbb W_j x_i - b_j \geq 1 - \xi_{i,j}$$

$$\xi_{i,j} \geq 0$$

$$\xi_{i:y_i=j,j} = 1$$

for $i=1, \dots, n$, $j=1, \dots, m $

$\mathbb W_i$ denotes the i-th row of the matrix $\mathbb W$, $x_i$ is a vector of length compatible with $\mathbb W$ and $\xi_{i:y_i=j,j} = 1$ means that we fix this $\xi_{i,j}$ to 1 if $y_i=j$

Any idea how to write the Lagrangian and then the dual this problem ?

Comment: If $\mathbb{W}_i$ is a row of the matrix, what does $\mathbb{W}_i^2$ in the objective mean?

Comment: scalar product of the row with itself